# madExcept, getting top of current stack

Tags: delphi, stack-trace, madexcept

In an delphi 2007 application, we have used madExcept to handle exeptions for us. We use the standard dialog, letting the user send us a report with mail if he want to.

We want to add a little to this functionality. If the user choose not to send a full report, we still want to log the exception to a file, but not a full report. We want the exception class and message, and the source file and line number.

The first two is easy, but I can't find a straight forward way of finding the latter.

I have the full exception report in the form of an `IMEException` interface. As far as I can see, the call stack is available only through the `BugReportSections` property, which gives me the stack in plain text.

In madStackTrace.pas, there is a `StackTrace( )`-function that should give me what I want. It takes a lot of parameters, and the documentation is a little short on information..

**Question:**
Does anybody know the right parameters to feed into `StackTrace( )`, so that it only return the top item of the stack from the thread where the exception was thrown?

Answer (score 5):

madStackTrace.pas has another function, `StackAddrToStr` that just takes a single address and returns the formatted text for it.  If you're in the `except` block for the crashing thread you can pass the global `ExceptAddr` variable to it.  If you're in one of the madExcept callbacks use `IMEException.ExceptAddr' instead.

Comment: Still returning a string, but this one lead me to GetMapFileInfos( ) from madMapFile.pas, which may give me what I want.

Comment: I think I may have found what I need for StackTrace, though: `StackTrace(true, false, false, @stack, exception.ExceptAddr, true, false);`

Comment: I'm sorry, but soon after this question, I switched workplace. I do remember solving the issue, but I no longer have access to the code to see the solution.
I'm not sure if its right to mark the answer as accepted. It's not a direct answer to the question, even though it was helpful (which earn it a upvote...)

Comment: madStackTrace.StackAddrToStr(ExceptAddr) gets the line number for me, thanks Craig!